# Web page with Google Maps and Weather Image only works in IE, not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

This webpage opens a Google maps and a weather gif image. It works fine in IE, but not in Chrome. Can someone tell me what I should change to make this work in Chrome?

*URL removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested on a separate page, capitalization matters. The script says map_canvas, while the div is named Map_canvas. Should be the same.